# Como colocar videos do UOL no JWplayer

Tags: php, vídeo

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso pegar vídeos do código `embed`  do player da UOL vídeos e por para funcionar no [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/). Eu achei o código abaixo, ele no caso pega a `url` e converte com tudo como a `url` da UOL. Mudou diretrizes, mas não está funcionando. Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso.

A [url](http://player.mais.uol.com.br/embed_v2.swf?mediaId=15444925&p=related) do video UOL.

O código de converter `url`:

```
<?php
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNÇÃO CURL PARA URL FILE DISABLE - SIMPLE XML LOAD
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

        function curlXML($url) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);       
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

            return $xml;
        }
        // Verifico se existe no servidor a função curl.
        function carrega_xml ($url) {
            if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')){
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
            } else {
                $xml = $this->curlXML($url);
            }
            return $xml;
        }

        $video = carrega_xml('http://videolog.uol.com.br/swfs/related/related-player-publicididade.php?id_video='.$_GET['v']);
        echo $video->item->video;
        if ($video->item->video_hd){
            echo $video->item->video_hd;
        }
    ?>
```

No caso, o código acima também gera link de download, mas preciso somente que ele funcione com a `url` atual. Desde já agradeço quem puder me auxiliar.

"**Alguem saberia me dizer alguma forma alternativa de obter a `url` dos vídeos do UOL, mas para poder colocar no JWPlayer, caso não haja solução para o funcionamento deste código**".

Comment: Alguem sabe como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não seja necessário `php`, e que seja o mesmo procedimento para incluir vídeos do `youtube`.

Segundo [esta indicação](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed) do suporte do JWPlayer o procedimento é o seguinte:

**1 - Adicione a biblioteca dentro da tag `head`**

Este é o link padrão, mas você também pode baixar a versão *Self-Hosted*:

```
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/YOUR_JW_PLAYER_ACCOUNT_TOKEN.js" ></script>
```

Você deve trocar o `YOUR_JW_PLAYER_ACCOUNT_TOKEN` pelo seu `token` do JWPlayer (este link pode ser encontrado na sua conta de usuário).

**2 - Incluir o código `embed` dentro da tag `body`**

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CjdLYBDUqw",
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
```

Para mais detalhes, vide o tutorial [na página do JWPlayer](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed).

Comment: Boa noite Gustavo, no caso o PHP dele me parece apenas para pegar o link e não os dados, outra coisa o jwplayer só consegue rodar videos do youtube, pois o youtube disponibiliza uma API para habilitar play/pause/stop/etc, acredito que o player do uol não tenha API (me corrija se eu estiver enganado), a não ser uma API para pegar a lista de videos: http://mais.uol.com.br/static/dev.vm

Comment: Hum, entendi, acho que você tem razão mesmo. No caso então o uol proíbe o que o AP quer fazer? Tipo, ele esconde a url justamente pra não ter jeito de rodar em outro site?

Comment: Acho que não proíbe, pois ele quer apenas compartilhar, a unica coisa não é possivel fazer é customizar o player como é feito no youtube, mas não é nenhuma proibição, é por que o player é limitado mesmo. Eu não tenho certeza se o player deles tem eventos como `.play()`, `.stop()`, `.getPosition()`, mas se tiver, então digamos que seria possível sim. Mas infelizmente não encontrei nenhuma documentação, o que me fazer pensar que não existe, uma pena mesmo.

Comment: E tentei correr atras disso também e não achei forma alguma de gerar uma URL pelo UOL que de pra por no JWPlayer isso e desanimador.E gustavox agradeço a ajuda só que o youtube o JWPlayer já dispõem compatibilidade, meu problema e mesmo com o UOL Mais que não consegui nenhum tutorial ou explicações de como fazer uma URL para poder por o FLY deles para rodar em outros player de vídeo online.